# Why "A" element click simulation does not work?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, blob

im working my website, where you can also download files and I want to make download progress bar using blob, but for some odd reason my click simulation for a element doesnt work, here is my code:

```
var _OBJECT_URL;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    _OBJECT_URL = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
    $(".downloadexecutor").attr('href', _OBJECT_URL);
    $(".downloadexecutor").attr('download', '<?php echo $file["File"]; ?>');
    $(".downloadexecutor").click();
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(_OBJECT_URL);
    }, 60 * 1000);
  }
});
request.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
  var percent_complete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
  alert(percent_complete + '%');
});
request.responseType = 'blob';
request.open('get', 'downloader.php');
request.send();
```

The element is already placed in the website just above the script, did anybody spot what I am doing wrong and how can I fix that?

Comment: jQuery's `click()` method triggers events registered through jQuery. It doesn't trigger the native click actions of the element. Call the native DOM `click()` method instead

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you!!!